# Remove rows that are contained (as sub-strings) in other rows

Tags: knime

I have a table like as follows:

```
This is a cat
This is a pet
This is a dog
is
a
is a
is
is a dog
That is a dog
```

I would like to end up with a table as follows:

```
This is a cat
This is a pet
This is a dog
That is a dog
```

Essentially remove the rows that are already contained (as sub-strings) in other rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a combination of all rows with the [Cross Joiner](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.crossjoin.CrossJoinerNodeFactory) node (both inputs are coming from your example). Followed by a [String Manipulation](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.stringmanipulation.StringManipulationNodeFactory) node (probably followed by a [String to Number](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.colconvert.stringtonumber.StringToNumberNodeFactory) node) or a [Java Snippet](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.jsnippet.JavaSnippetNodeFactory) node you can assign `1` or `0` if the original is contained in the latter or not. After you can [GroupBy](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.groupby.GroupByNodeFactory) based on the original column and sum the `0`/`1` values. With a [Row Filter](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.base.node.preproc.filter.row.RowFilterNodeFactory) you can keep only those rows which contain `1` in the sum column.

(Please note that because of the **Cross Joiner** it can create quite large tables. Maybe the [Distance measure](https://www.knime.com/wiki/distance-measure) [nodes](https://www.knime.com/distance-matrix-nodes) can solve this problem more efficiently.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact nature of your dataset, but if you had columns each with some text value (like in the picture), you could treat each row as an itemset and use the Item Set Finder (after a suitable conversion to a bit vector) to find the maximal itemsets.

The maximal itemsets would be the rows that are supersets of other rows.

[image: Sample Workflow]
[image: Example Table]
[image: Output Table]

Comment: Can you explain how to get the bit vector?